What does testosterone do in a womans body?
I recently took a blood test and had low testosterone. I am looking for information about testosterone in a woman's body.

This is very broad. Googling 'effects of testosterone in females' will give you plenty of info that covers the basics. Is there something specific you're wondering about? Better, on topic questions provide evidence of your own research (quote and link) and a specific question (e.g. testosterone and bone strength) which can be done with an edit. Also, your doctor is the person to talk to about your health, as it's personal and specific to you/your situation. Thanks.
